# $scope.$on is not listening

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I have an app that manually bootstraps after all my controllers are registered. I then want to see that when a user logs in, that their account has been verified. Unfortunately my scope listener isn't working and can't catch the broadcast emmited from my loggin controller. The code for my account verification is bellow:

```
class CMSAccountCtrl

  constructor: (@$scope, @$rootScope, @$location, @$http, @APGlobalState) ->
    console.log @$scope 
    @$scope.$on 'CMSAccountCtrl-verify', (event, value) =>
      console.log 'cms account ctrl should have verified'
      @verify()

    @$scope.verify = () =>
      @verify()

  verify: () =>
    @$http({
        'method': 'POST'
        'url': "#{window.ap_base_uri}/caas/account/verify"
        'data': {
          'apCookie': @APGlobalState.get 'cookie'
        }
      }).success((data, status, headers, config) =>
        # Do something
        console.log(data)
        if data.isVerified == 'yes'
          @$rootScope.$broadcast 'CMSLoginCtrl-showToolbar'
        else
          @$scope.alert = {
            msg: "You're account as not been verified. Please re-check your email."
          }
      ).error((data, status, headers, config) =>
        # Do somethings
      )



if !window.apInject?
  window.apInject = {}

if !window.CMSControllers?
  window.CMSControllers = {}

# This executes before bootstrap, but after angular.module 'myModule', []
window.apInject.CMSAccountCtrl = (app) ->
  app.controller 'CMSAccountCtrl', [
    '$scope'
    '$rootScope'
    '$location'
    '$http'
    'APGlobalState'
    CMSAccountCtrl
  ]

window.CMSControllers.CMSAccountCtrl = CMSAccountCtrl
```

Oddly enough, my @$scope.$on 'listener' works for some of my controllers but fails for others even though they all implement the same structure. Why isn't my listener registering?

Answer (score 0):

You can either $emit an event or $broadcast an event. The difference between the two is that $emit will dispatch the event upwards the scope hierarchy. However $broadcast will dispatch the event downwards to its child scopes.

In your scenario when our $scope.$broadcast is not working try to do $scope.$emit as the receiver would be of upwards level.

Comment: You have reversed what $broadcast and $emit do. Broadcast goes down, emit up.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends upon how is you controller and hence the scopes are setup. Broadcast goes down from the scope it is called, emit goes up from the scope it is called.

If your login and CMSAccount controller do not share the same scope hierarchy (parent-child), i.e then neither $scope.$emit or $scope.$boadcast would work. You would need to use $rootScope.$broadcast in that case and the subscriber can use $scope.$on.

You also have to make sure that the controller is already loaded when the event is published else the controller will never receive the mail. For example if event is raised from one ng-view partial and subscribed by another ng-view, it would never work.